# selectSingleNode overwrite/override crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

basically ive been tasked with fixing an none cross browser application. problem is its over use of the .selectSingleNode function. (which ofc is IE only).

i have a replacement being:

```
function selectOneNode(key, node) {
try {
    Response = node.selectSingleNode(key);
}
catch (err) {

    var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
    var nsResolver = xpe.createNSResolver(node.ownerDocument == null ? node.documentElement : node.ownerDocument.documentElement);
    var results = xpe.evaluate(key, node, nsResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
    //Response.ErrorNumber = results.singleNodeValue.text.toString().ToInt(); 
    Response = results.singleNodeValue;
}
return Response;
```

}

but this .selectSingleNode function is used well over 2000 times in many files, but have no idea how to override the .selectSingleNode function, so i don't need change every instance.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to override some function you can just write it once again. I've had similar problem but with alert function. I've just done such thing:

```
function alert(){
//custom code goes here
}
```